# Exception while initializing the PortletRequestListener

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

Getting following exception while running `tomcat` with `PortletRequestListner`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:77)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:37)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.PortletRequestListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstanceFactory.newInstance(InstanceFactory.java:52)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstanceFactory.newInstance(InstanceFactory.java:27)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListener(SecurePluginContextListener.java:304)
```

I am new to liferay.

Not able to resolve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand you are new to Liferay, I hope you are not new to programming :)
The stack-trace clearly says that you have not provided the necessary JAR file in your portlet's WEB-INF/lib folder:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.PortletRequestListener
```

Hope you can connect the dots from here!

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, yes I know jar is missing but want to know which jar exactly I have to add. I tried with spring and liferay portlet jars but it is not working for me

Comment: It's pretty easy: I did a quick Google and found that it is part of spring-web.jar. Reference: http://hobione.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/javalangclassnotfoundexception-orgspringframeworkwebcontextcontextloaderlistener/